# Multithreaded Script Does not Increment Order Number Properly for a Django Database Entry

Tags: django, database, postgresql, multithreading, scripting

I have an images endpoint like this: `/api/properties/image/` and I can post an image to the endpoint, and that saves an image link to the Postgres database. This line of code handles the logic:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    property_id = self.context['property_ad_id']

    # This line handles the update
    order = PropertyImage.objects.filter(ad_id=property_id).count() + 1
    return PropertyImage.objects.create(ad_id=property_id, order=order, **validated_data)
```

From the above, it counts how many images are currently in the database, stores it in memory then increments it by one, and finally, it creates a new image with that incremented value as its order.

The operation works as intended until I use a multithreaded script as the one below to mass-populate the images:

```
def single_property_upload(image_file, property_id):
    BASE_URL_PROPERTY = base(property_id=property_id)
    with image_file.open(mode="rb") as f:
        image_data = f.read()

    files_data = {"image": ("image.jpg", image_data, "image/jpeg")}
    response = requests.post(BASE_URL_PROPERTY, files=files_data)

def post_images(image_files, id):
    threads = []
    for image_file in image_files:
        # Create a new thread for each image upload
        t = threading.Thread(target=single_property_upload, args=(image_file, id))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


def populate_images():
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        image_files = [
            Path.cwd() / "house_images2" / f"{str(randint(1, 160))}.jpg"
            for i in range(4)
        ]
        post_images(image_files, str(i))
        print(f"Property {i} populated successfully")
    print("Done")
    
populate_images()
```

When I run this script, I get the following output:

```
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_BfBIGGA.jpg'}
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_xW729Bu.jpg'}
{'order': 3, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_6eOphsM.jpg'}
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_EOeLX7W.jpg'}
Property 1 populated successfully                                                           }
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_q8c25vT.jpg'}
{'order': 2, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_C5nolKw.jpg'}
{'order': 2, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_uGxF085.jpg'}
{'order': 2, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_LQZJ92P.jpg'}
Property 2 populated successfully                                                           }
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_frbvPUx.jpg'}
{'order': 2, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_0PCqmzH.jpg'}
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_RLMFwBL.jpg'}
{'order': 3, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_EmD6SEH.jpg'}
Property 3 populated successfully                                                           }
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_CmmNXqt.jpg'}
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_bIkRg9J.jpg'}
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_zHLAAhz.jpg'}
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_SDKVs57.jpg'}
Property 4 populated successfully                                                           }
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_oHhJ4DZ.jpg'}
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_5oEtCAl.jpg'}
{'order': 1, 'image': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/properties/images/image_dq8BKjM.jpg'}
```

As shown above, the order numbers are not incrementing properly, probably due to multiple threads counting how many images are in the database at the exact same time, so instead of order to be 1, 2, 3, 4 it'll be 1, 1, 1, 1.

I tried using F() queries and transaction.atomic() :

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        property_id = self.context['property_ad_id']

        # Use a database transaction to ensure atomicity
        with transaction.atomic():
            # Use select_for_update to lock the rows during counting
            order = PropertyImage.objects.filter(ad_id=property_id).select_for_update().count()

            # Use update with F() expression to perform atomic increment
            PropertyImage.objects.filter(ad_id=property_id).update(order=F('order') + 1)

            # Create the new image with the calculated order
            return PropertyImage.objects.create(ad_id=property_id, order=order + 1, **validated_data)
```

I also tried writing the query manually:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    property_id = self.context['property_ad_id']

    # Use a database transaction to ensure atomicity
    with transaction.atomic():
        # Use a raw SQL query to fetch the count with a lock
        order_query = PropertyImage.objects.raw(
            f'SELECT id, ad_id, "order" FROM property_properties_propertyadimage WHERE ad_id = %s FOR UPDATE',
            [property_id]
        )

        # Calculate the order by counting the results
        order = len(list(order_query))
        result = PropertyImage.objects.create(ad_id=property_id, order=order + 1, **validated_data)
        # Create the new image with the calculated order
        print(f'Updated Property: {property_id} at time: {time()}')
        print(connection.queries)
        return result
```

...all to no avail. The same issues persisted.

Any database experts here? How do i fix this issue please? Is there a special way I can lock reads until the object is incremented?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your basic algorithm being a form of *max(x)+1* is in a multithreaded/multiple user environment a virtual *guarantee* of getting duplicate values. The solution is let the database manager handle creating the `order number` (see [Serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) and/or [Generated ... identity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). You do not want to lock reads unless you want you want to bring performance to a halt, locking reads will by its very nature result in singled thread performance. NOTE: Gaps are normal and expected.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if there are any constructs in the django ORM itself to help fix this?

Comment: I do not know *django ORM*. My recommendation would be check your documentation. A second option just google it. A 15sec search for *django ORM serial* brought me to [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-sequences/).

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into django-sequences. It seems like it solves the issue quite well.